# Reading binary data (byte order)

Tags: python

I am confused as to how I would read binary data from the file described below. The document that describes how this data is created states the following:

There is a "start of log file record", and the format is such that there is a plaintext message terminated with a ctrl-Z '0x1a' (end of file for DOS/Windows), ctrl-D '0x04' (end of file for Unix), and null '0x00' (in that order, according to design doc).

Then, there is the value 0x12345678 (length 4 bytes, to allow an arbitrary decoder to determine byte storage order)

After that lives the meat of the data.

My code to read this file:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
while True:
    byte = f.read(1)
    if byte.encode('hex') == '1a':            #  ctrl-z
        if s[i+1].encode('hex') == '04':      #  ctrl-D
            if s[i+2].encode('hex') == '00':  #  null
                print s[i:i+8].encode('hex')
                break
```

prints >> `1a04007856341200`

As you can see, the `0x12345678` is hidden in there. I have learned from my research that this means the data is stored "little endian". My tools now are (I feel) making things way more difficult than I need them to be. For example, the below code picks out the year (YYYY) the file was created

```
i = year_location_in_file  # just a pointer

created_year = struct.unpack('<cc', s[i:i+2])
print 'created_year as hex:', created_year

created_year = int(''.join([e for e in created_year][::-1]).encode('hex'), 16)
print 'created year as int:', created_year
```

prints:

`>> created_year as hex: ('\xdd', '\x07')`

`>> created year as int: 2013`

I have spent significant time trying to understand all of the suggested questions and reading everything I can possibly Google. I am hoping that answers will assist me as well as anyone else struggling to understand byte ordering in binary files. Thank you community.

EDIT: using `print(repr(open(filename, 'rb').read(600)))` gives

> > `....sometext\xd4\xb4\x97\x1a\x04\x00xV4\x12\x00U\x01\.....`

- B

Comment: Instead of thanks in advance I'd like a single *'?'* much more, to know what to focus on. I even tried Ctrl+F and *"problem"*. Failed to find any.

Comment: What is the binary stuff at the end supposed to represent? You show 13 bytes (with an extra backslash at the end), but you don't say how they should be interpreted.

Comment: @Blckknght that is the results of the above print statement. I was just showing that the value I am looking for (0x12345678) is in there as xV4\x12\

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble comes from using `c` as your code to `struct.unpack` rather than a larger sized type. `c` is a character, which is only one byte long (which means the byte order is immaterial). Instead, use `h` for a two byte short integer, or `l` for a four byte long int (use capitol letters if you need an unsigned value).

```
year_data = b"\x77\x07"                        # bytes sliced from the binary file
year = struct.unpack("<h", year_data)          # unpacked to int in one go
```